# Writing a conditional ng-init statement for new items in the scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat to create a set of div todo items. What I would like to have happen is automatically apply the "editing = true" styling to this newly created item, and apply focus if possible.

```
<div class="item" ng-class="{'editing-item': editing, 'edited': todo.edited, 'completed': todo.completed}" 
ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy: 'completed'" ng-init ="todo.completed = false">
```

I also have an add button for creating new items

```
<div class="add">
    <span class="add" ng-click="addTodo()">
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is the code for "addTodo()"

```
    $scope.addTodo = function(){
      var todo = {name: "..."};
      $scope.todos.unshift(todo);
    };
```

When this new item is created, can I conditionally set editing = true within ng-init, or is this only possible through using jQuery in some way? I've looked into doing this by using the index number of the newly created div but have had no luck. Bonus points for help setting focus to this input item, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Keep `editing` property in `todo` object and access it in `ng-repeat`

```js
$scope.addTodo = function() {
  var todo = {
    name: "...",
    editing: true
  };
  $scope.todos.unshift(todo);
};
```

```html
<div class="item" ng-class="{'editing-item': todo.editing, 'edited': todo.edited, 'completed': todo.completed}" ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy: 'completed'" ng-init="todo.completed = false">
```